# Swap class with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can I use jQuery to replace certain class (.a) in input fields with another (.b) one in my table?

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td>Field 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="a"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Field 2</td>
    <td><textarea class="a"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$("#myTable").find(":input").removeClass('a').addClass('b');
```

See:  http://jsfiddle.net/fqXvT/1/

Comment: I can't replace all, I need it to be done in the table with ID="myTable" Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, just came to realize that I also have one text area in that table, which also needs a class swap.

Comment: @santa: use `:input` selector which will choose all input field types.

Comment: @NickLarson - I thought yours would work but it didn't in jsfiddle, updated with similar logic that seems to work

Answer (score 4):

@brendan's works, but in case you have a situation where you don't want that intermediate state between the removeClass() and the addClass() (which, I'm not sure even happens in the DOM), try toggleClass() with both the class you want to turn off and the one you want to turn on:

[toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

You start with "a", then swap to "b" on event (or use the same call to swap back when the reverse event occurs):

```
$("#myTable").find(":input").toggleClass("a b");
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery UI you could use the [`switchClass` function](https://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/):

```js
$selector.switchClass('a', 'b');
```